# Minix3 process table (proc.h)

Tags: c, operating-system, int, minix

Anyone know why certain fields in proc.h in Minix are char, when I thought they'd be int?

```
 37   char p_ticks_left;            /* number of scheduling ticks left */

 38   char p_quantum_size;          /* quantum size in ticks */
```

So, if we want to add a new "int" field should we make it a char?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `char` is big enough to hold all the necessary values, why not use it? Of course, `int` may be somewhat more performant, but at the same time `char` is usually smaller.

I believe you can use any type that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

consider from design, maybe It's enough to save value of "number of scheduling ticks left" and "quantum size in ticks". and size of char is smaller than size of int.